# How to keep the browser open on client's machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I am developing an ASP.net web application for a school project. The website will be used for monitoring the usage of computers in an internet cafe. I know that this kind of an application is better when form-based but I am required to develop it as a web application. I'd like to capture the start time of a user(customer) upon login to my website. So basically I don't want the user to be able to access any application in the computer unless he logs into my website. I am thinking of achieving this by keeping the browser open on the client's computer and not allowing them to close it. Is there a way to do that in ASP.net and without using any other native application? I am using C# by the way.

Thanks in advance :)

P. S. I am open for any other ways for achieving this :)

Comment: No, you cannot do this without a native app running on the client machine. Websites do not have that kind of power.

Comment: I believe the better way to do this would be to pass a security token to the client that is saved in their cookies. This token can be access by the application and registered for a renewable certain period of time or indefinitely on the back end in a db or something to the effect. That would be my suggestion at this point.

Comment: the only way i can think of doing this is by disguise your website as desktop application. There are some frameworks available where you can create desktop application in web technologies. In that way you'll have advantages of both areas. But a simple website cannot do what you are trying to do. Users can disable `beforeunload` event in browsers. So you can't count on that.

Comment: You have to use some kind of launcher application to accomplish this. If it's for a school project, you can probably safely write the launcher alongside it. Alternatively you could mod a browser, but that sounds like a lot more work.

Comment: @user1274820 Hi thanks for your reply. My instructor also mentioned something about making the browser modal. Is that what you mean by "mod a browser"? Can you give me a good reference for that? Thanks

Comment: I don't think we're understanding how this is supposed to work (at least I'm not). Are you saying the website will run the cafe (from a kiosk type setup) in which you log in, and then you go over to the computer and log in or something? Or are you saying you sit down at a computer and there is a browser window and nothing else ... once you log in, it goes away and you can access the rest of the computer? OR, are you saying that all there is on the computer is a browser and that's the only application they can use, but you can't access the internet until you log in?

Comment: If it's the second one (a browser keeps you from accessing the computer), that is impossible to secure without some other operating system mod or native application (as everyone has said). Best you can do is "try" to stop them from leaving the page with code like this: `window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Are you sure you wanna leave my website?';//Displays an confirm box and, if you click cancel, you will stay on the page. Otherwise, you'll leave the page
}`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the second one. I'd like to know about mod since I am not allowed to use any native application. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the past you use to be able to call onbeforeunload to do this or reopen the web page if it was closed, this was removed for security reasons.

Currently there is no way to prevent a browser from closing.

Maybe if you are allowed to use an HTA (Html Application) you will be able to open that in a full window and use onbeforeunload or activexobjects to prevent the hta from closing.

Other then that you need to create an native application that prevents the website from closing.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I am not allowed to use a native application application. I have edited my question. I will try your suggestion on using HTA and onbeforunload event and let you know if it works. Thanks a lot :)